# Git committing to a new remote?

Tags: git

I checked out a branch based off another remote branch by setting it as tracking branch.

```
git checkout -b bar origin/foo
```

Now I want bar to go into origin/bar, which is different than foo. I agree I should have

```
git checkout foo
git pull --all
git checkout -b bar
```

in the first place. How do I solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git push -u origin bar:foo
```

Means "push the `bar` branch to the `origin` remote (with the name `foo` on the remote end) and set up `bar` to push and pull from `origin/foo` in the future".